# What is the equivalent of Entity Framework in the world of Oracle shops?

Tags: orm, entity-framework, oracle, middleware

Within the world of developers/firms specializing in building/deploying solutions built around software built/sold by Oracle (aka "Oracle houses"), **what ORM middleware is considered as the "industry standard"** (if any), based on your experience?

We have limited experience on Oracle's stack, so would appreciate insights from folks who have more experience in it. This might impact our product roadmap.

Comment: what is "Oracle houses"?

Comment: 1) Can someone explain the close votes? This is a real question as relates to our (sw) business's strategy. We would be very interested in learning from people's insights before we jump the gun. 2) @gnat: A firm that specializes in making solution built around Oracle based software

Comment: What is "Oracle based software"?

Comment: @gnat: Presumably software built and/or sold by Oracle, right? Not sure if you're being pedantic or genuine but I've edited my question for clarity and specificity.

Comment: I've seen a project that developed .NET applications serving Oracle DB, would that qualify as "Oracle shop"?

Comment: @gnat: So pedantic it is. While you're at it, others managed to offer more productive answers that actually helped us with our concern.

Comment: @Sid - I can see how this question is important to you, but unless there's only one choice for an Oracle ORM, I don't see how you can expect anyone to tell you what is the best one. Check the FAQ's.

Comment: @JeffO: Not 'best' since that's subjective but "most often deployed" as seen by a programmer in their experience. Sort of like a mental histogram off frequency. We had no idea if there was 1 or multiple ORM middlewares - hence this question.

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET you're able to use EF with the Oracle Data Provider. You can also use nhibernate for a RDBMS agnostic framework.

If you're in the Java world you have a few big ORM choices: Hibernate, TopLink and I've also come across Apache OpenJPA being used. In my experience with Java, Hibernate tends to be used more often and I've not commercially seen TopLink used before.

For an Oracle house, the *typical stack* would be:

- Java / JEE
- An application server, I typically see Jetty or Tomcat
- Hibernate
- Spring
- Eclipse for development
- Maven for building

Comment: A true Oracle house would be using WebLogic for the app server, and TopLink/JPA for the ORM layer.  If they're *really* drinking the kool-aid, they'll also be using JDeveloper as their IDE.

Comment: Thats a good point. I guess the places I've worked who are all Oracle aren't as Oracle as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the client language used. If you use C# to access an Oracle DB, you might use EF (and suffer the performance problems it has with Oracle, not sure if they were introduced deliberately :) ).

If you use Java you might want to use Hibernate. If you're an all-Oracle shop this is probably what you'll end up using.

There are others, and any of them are available for use with an Oracle DB, nHibernate for example!

Comment: An _all_ Oracle shop would probably prefer [TopLink](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/overview/index.html) to Hibernate (which would be a very good reason to _not_ be an all Oracle shop).